# Добавить атрибут rel='noffolow' PHP

Tags: php

Доброго времени. Есть строка

`<a href='http://ru.stackoverflow.com/'>http://ru.stackoverflow.com/</a>`

и есть код добавления атрибута rel='nofollow'

```
$re = "/'?\\\"?((http|https|ftp):\\/\\/(?!site.com|site.com)[\\w\\.\\/\\-=?#]+)'?\\\"?/"; 
$str = $all_text; 
$subst = "\"$1\" rel=\"nofollow\""; 
$all_text = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

 $all_text=$all_text;
```

Данный код ставит атрибут noffolow в саму ссылку и в название ссылки . Как можно скорректировать, чтобы не трогать само название ссылки  ? Спасибо

Comment: `$all_text = preg_replace("/href/", "rel=\"\nofollow" href", $str)` не?

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум 2 пути:

1:

```
$all_text = str_replace('href', 'rel="nofollow" href', $str);
```

2:

```
$re = '/href=/i'; 
$str = '<a href="http://ru.stackoverflow.com/">http://ru.stackoverflow.com/</a>';
$subst = "rel=\"nofollow\" href=";
$all_text = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Можно придумать и более изящные решения )))